# softlayer api: get the monthly total cost of consumption by SoftLayer_Account.get_invoices and SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice.getInvoiceTotalAmount

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

BACK GROUND:
I want to calculate the monthly total consumption of a account by sl api.

CURRENTLY METHOD:
Firstly, I use SoftLayer_Account.get_invoices to get the list of invoices. Each invoice item as {startingBalance:xx, endingBalance:xx, id:xx, typeCode:xx}

Secondly, for each invoice, I task its id as params to call SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice.getInvoiceTotalAmount, the total amount can be returned.

PROBLEM:
I found that the total_amount of typeCode=RECURRING is positive. And tohers is negative. My questions: 
1)if I just want to calculate the total consumption, which type of typeCode(NEW,RECURRING,ONE-TIME-CHARGE, CREDIT...) I want to handle?
2)For each type typeCode, the total amount may be positive and negative, what is the diffirent?
3)getInvoiceTotalAmount returns value‘ absolute some time not equals to abs(endingBalance - startingBalance), could you tell me what are the relation ship between these params?

Answer (score 0):

the invoice total amount is calculated like this:

```
Total = RECURRING FEE + (recurring fee* RECURRING FEE TAX RATE) + ONE TIME FEE + (ONE TIME FEE * ONE TIME FEE TAX RATE) + LABOR FEE + (LABOR FEE * LABOR FEE TAX RATE) + SETUPT FEE + (SETUP FEE * FEEE TAX RATE)
```

I do not have negative values, but perhaps is due to your account has some kind of discount for some items.

if you want to calculate total consuption for an invoice I recomed you just to use the method either SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getInvoiceTotalAmount or the [SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTotalAmount](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTotalAmount)  to get accurate data.